# LibGDX input processor

Tags: java, input, libgdx

I'm beginning to make a game and for some reason I can't seem to set the input processor.

Reading through the API I can set the input processor using Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GameInputProcessor());

But libgdx doesn't seem to recognize the setInputProcessor method at all.

`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GameInputProcessor());`

so far for my inputprocessor class

```
 public class GameInputProcessor extends InputAdapter{

     //these keys 
     public boolean keyDown(int k){
        return true;
    }

   public boolean keyUp(int k){
    return true;
 }

}
```

Why is it not setInputProcessor() as a method?

Comment: Make sure you're importing: `import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;`

Comment: I am importing this. setInputProcessor takes an InputProcessor as an argument. Can I give it a class like GameInputProcessor instead?